# Transform string into array and the run sort method in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, split, ejs

I am trying to use the split method to create a new array and then use sort to rearrange alphabetically. The issue I am having is that when I attempt to split, it is not splitting evenly across the string. How can I remove all spaces and then transform string into array?

I am running this line of code:

```
$(".track").innerText().split(" ").sort()

<%tracks.forEach(function(track){%>
            <tr>
                <td class="track">
                    <a href="/tracks/<%=track.id%>">
                    <%= track.title%><br></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%});%>
```

Comment: Where is your actuall (rendered) HTML?

Comment: How does your string look? give an example.

Comment: Can you give an example? If you just want to remove all spaces and then split the string into characters you can do it this way. `s.replace(/ /g, "").split("")`

Comment: It is returning "
     
     Bassy
    
     
     Chicago
    
     
     The Bay
    "

Comment: I am trying to form it into ["Bassy", "Chicago", "The Bay"]

Comment: Also I am using ejs to render the HTML

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) with [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) then calling [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) after [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)ting the array:

```
$(".track").map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
}).get().sort();
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrb3aq4n/)**